# Why do I get an error when I try to find the selected option for a select?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code:

```
        $('select.update-grid')
            .each(function () {
                var id = this.id.replace('modal', '');
                var sel = this.find("option:selected").text();
                var val = this.val()
                $('#input' + id)
                    .val(val)
                    .attr('title', sel);
            })
```

It works by finding all the selects with a class of update-grid. When I step through this code I get an error on the line starting with "var sel".

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'
```

Does anyone know what can be wrong with my code?

Comment: try `$(this).find` or what i like to do is assign it like `var $t = $(this), id=$t.id.replace('modal', ''), sel=$t.find('option:selected').text(), val = $t.val();` if it's gonna be used more then once.

Comment: @TI Doing `$t.id` is incorrect, since you're (supposed to be) accessing a property of the DOM element itself, not a property of a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are running .each() then this refers to the current select.update-grid DOM element, not a jquery Reference of it:

```
$('select.update-grid')
    .each(function () {
    var grid = $(this);
        var id = this.id.replace('modal', '');
        var sel = grid.find("option:selected").text();
        var val = this.value;
        $('#input' + id)
            .val(val)
            .attr('title', sel);
    });
```

is what you are looking for I think.

Answer (score 4):

### To the point:

The object you have in `this` is an HTMLElement object and not a jQuery object.

You can correct this by using `$(this)` instead of `this` or better yet by assigning `$(this)` to a variable and using that variable everywhere.

### As a side note:

Approach debugging an error by first checking if it's syntactic; then checking if it's an API "feature" that you didn't know about (the current case); only then checking if it's a conceptual issue (can't be done this way).

Try to isolate your problem, take it out of context until you have the smallest piece of code that can reproduce the error. This reveals the very general nature of the error and allows you to better understand the (rather generic and sometimes cryptical) error "message".

Look the error message up on the Internet and find others in similar or different predicaments and check out how similar things get fixed but also how different things get fixed. After that you can ask a documented question and understand the answers.

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
$(this).find(...
```

Inside each method, this reference to DOM element not a jquery object

Answer (score 1):

just use this

```
 $("select option:selected").
```

or in you code you just misss $(this) just writ that insted of this

```
$(this).find(':selected').text();
```

or to check

```
alert($(this).find(":selected").text());
```

Comment: `$(this).()` is a syntax error you meant `$(this).find('option:selected')`.